# accessing auto-generated fields and querying

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following piece of code in ItemController.groovy

```
def list = {
    params.max = 60
    def storeYYId = params.id

        [itemInstanceList: Item.list(params), itemInstanceTotal: Item.count()]
}
```

I have the following in Item.groovy:

```
class Item {
    String itemName
    static belongsTo = [store:Store]


    static constraints = {
        itemName(blank:false)
        storeId()
    }
}
```

This gives me an error since it tells me that there is no storeId property, but there is, since store_id is a foreign key to the Store table in the corresponding database.

Question1.  How do I tell grails to let me access the properties of domains that are autogenerated by GORM, like the id and storeId in this case?

Question2.  What code should I write in my ItemController.groovy in my list action, in order to retrieve only a list of items where the storeId == storeYYId ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question1. How do I tell grails to let me access the properties of
>   domains that are autogenerated by GORM, like the id and storeId in
>   this case?

You should be able to access autogenerated properties in exactly the same way as you access properties that you define. The reason you're getting an error is because Grails does not automatically generate a `storeId` property for the `Item` class, the only properties it will autogenerate are `version` and `id` (for both `Item` and `Store`).

> Question2. What code should I write in my ItemController.groovy in my
>   list action, in order to retrieve only a list of items where the
>   storeId == storeYYId ?

You'll need to write either a HQL or criteria query to retrieve these items. The criteria query would look something like this (untested)

```
// Get all items that have storeId = 6
def storeId = 6

def items = Item.withCriteria {
    store {
        eq('id', storeId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also simple do Item.findAllByStore(Store.get(storeId))

Comment: @Gregg that solution is definitely simpler, but I expect it would cause two queries to be issued, which I wanted to avoid

Comment: sure.  get() always tries to pull from cache, however.  So the hit is likely negligible.  I suppose you could also have done Item.findAllByStore(Store.load(storeId)) which would suffice and not even need to go to cache.